Merge without Changing Master .gitignore or Committing Ignored Items
I've created a fork of one repository, to which I've added content to ignored files and removed the files from .gitignore to start tracking them.
Now, I want to merge changes from that fork into the original repo, but I don't want to change the .gitignore file in the original repo at all, meaning that I want to drop all the changes I made to the files that were in the .gitignore file in the original repo.
e.g.:
What I have right now:
# .gitignore on original-repo master
forget-me\**\*
remember-to-forget-me

# .gitignore on fork-repo master
remember-to-forget-me

# file structure on original-repo master
root
| folder-1
|- file-a
| folder-2
|- file-b
| folder-3
|- file-c

# file structure on fork-repo master
root
| folder-1
|- file-a
| folder-2
|- file-b
| folder-3
|- file-c
| folder-4
|- file-d
| forget-me
|- i-didnt-forget-this
|- i-didnt-forget-this-either

What I want:
# .gitignore on original-repo master expected after merge
forget-me\**\*
remember-to-forget-me

# file structure on original-repo master expected after merge
root
| folder-1
|- file-a
| folder-2
|- file-b
| folder-3
|- file-c
| folder-4
|- file-d

Note that folder-4 and contents were added, but not forget-me or its contents
What I tried:
I tried the following steps (using the example)

Create a new branch on fork-repo named to-merge
Switch to to-merge on fork-repo
Rewrite .gitignore on to-merge to exactly match .gitignore on original-repo
Commit changes to .gitignore to to-merge
Push to-merge from fork-repo to original-repo on GitHub
Create a pull request on original-repo from to-merge to master on GitHub
Merge the pull request on GitHub

What I got:
# .gitignore on original-repo master actual after merge
forget-me\**\*
remember-to-forget-me

# file structure on original-repo master actual after merge
root
| folder-1
|- file-a
| folder-2
|- file-b
| folder-3
|- file-c
| folder-4
|- file-d
| forget-me
|- i-didnt-forget-this
|- i-didnt-forget-this-either

Note that forget-me and its contents were saved even though they are in .gitignore
What I did after:
To undo my changes, I reverted merging the pull request. I may squash the commits on original-repo later to remove the old data.
Notes:
My next best guess is that I can do the following between steps 4 and 5 of what I tried doing.
git rm -r --cached forget-me
git add .
git commit -m "Remove ignored files"

But I don't know for sure if that's where the problems cropped up.
BTW, Don't worry about the security of the affected project. The 'forget-me' folder didn't contain any software secrets. We're talking about Dungeons and Dragons campaign notes (original-repo is for players and fork-repo is for GM eyes only). Theoretically, my players can read this in the git history, but they don't have the technical knowledge or interest in stealing a look at my notes.
edit: minor changes to headings.

Why do you change the .gitignore file at all, if you don't want it changed? Why do you track files if you don't want them merged? I don't there's anything in Git that can do that automatically. You can however git merge --no-commit, make your desired changes, then commit the merge. (or merge with a follow-up amend, or even simply a commit that remove the files again)



fork-repo is a separate project to original-repo with a superset of content.


I track the files on fork-repo, not original-repo


I want to commit some changes to the repo, but not the ones that would break original-repo's .gitignore


